# LINQ - How to insert null DateTime into database column?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Using LINQ, how do I insert a null value into a SQL Server 2008 DateTime column?

The code below inserts "1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM",
But I want to insert "NULL" instead

```
CreatDate = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null
```

Comment: Did you verify the column is NULLable?

Comment: Try `CreatDate = null` or `DBNull` instead of `SqlDateTime.Null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that the column in the DB is set to allow NULL and your entity property, "CreateDate" is defined as "DateTime? CreateDate {get;set;}". Then, simply set "CreateDate = null".

Answer (score 0):

Your `CreateDate` property needs to be declared `Nullable<DateTime>` (aka `DateTime?`).  Then, you can set that property on your Linqed-up object to `null` (not `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null`, just plain old C# `null`) and you should get the desired result.  This of course assumes that your SQL table has the column properly defined to allow NULLs and that your definition for the column in the DBML also allows them.